# React checklist sort not updating

Tags: arrays, reactjs, sorting

We are trying to sort a checklist based on whether the item is checked or not. If an item is checked, it is then moved to the bottom of the list.

The index of the item gets updated succesfully (so once the first item gets checked, it is moved to the bottom, index is changed to 1 instead of 0 and the item that used to be index 1 is now index 1).

However, if we nog click on the item with index 1, the item with index 0 get's checked for some reason (rather than the item with index 1 being unchecked).

We tried some things, but have no clue what is causing this, so any ideas would help a lot.

Thanks!

```
const database = {
  "Design Checklist" : {
    "icon" : "ti-help",
    "items" : [ {
      "badExamplePicture" : "https://res.cloudinary.com/ootje/image/upload/v1474832696/DSC01717_ctd4k0.jpg",
      "checked" : false,
      "collapsed" : true,
      "desc" : "Desc.",
      "goodExamplePicture" : "https://res.cloudinary.com/ootje/image/upload/v1474832696/DSC01717_ctd4k0.jpg",
      "itemName" : "Item",
      "labels" : [ "Colors", "Layout" ],
      "quickWin" : 1
    }, {
      "badExamplePicture" : "https://res.cloudinary.com/ootje/image/upload/v1474832696/DSC01717_ctd4k0.jpg",
      "checked" : false,
      "collapsed" : true,
      "desc" : "Description.",
      "goodExamplePicture" : "https://res.cloudinary.com/ootje/image/upload/v1474832696/DSC01717_ctd4k0.jpg",
      "itemName" : "Someitem",
      "labels" : [ "Layout" ],
      "quickWin" : 2
    } ],
    "name" : "Design Checklist"
  }
};



class Checklists2 extends React.Component {
  state = {
    allChecklists: null,
    selectedChecklist: "Design Checklist",
    searchTerm: ""
  };

  componentWillMount = () => {

        this.setState({ allChecklists: database});

  };

 check = indexOfModifiedItem => {
    const isChecked = this.state.allChecklists[this.state.selectedChecklist]
      .items[indexOfModifiedItem].checked;

    this.setState({
      allChecklists: update(this.state.allChecklists, {
        [this.state.selectedChecklist]: {
          items: { [indexOfModifiedItem]: { checked: { $set: !isChecked } } }
        }
      })
    });
  };

  collapse = indexOfModifiedItem => {
    const isCollapsed = this.state.allChecklists[this.state.selectedChecklist]
      .items[indexOfModifiedItem].collapsed;

    this.setState({
      allChecklists: update(this.state.allChecklists, {
        [this.state.selectedChecklist]: {
          items: {
            [indexOfModifiedItem]: { collapsed: { $set: !isCollapsed } }
          }
        }
      })
    });
  };


  searchItems = () => {
    this.setState({ searchTerm: this.search.value });
  };

  render() {
    return (
<div>
                {this.state.allChecklists[this.state.selectedChecklist].items.filter(item => {
                    if (item.itemName.includes(this.state.searchTerm))
                      return true;
                    return false;
                  })
                  .sort((item,item2) => {
                    if(item.checked) return 1
                    else return 0
                  }) 
                  .map((item, i) => {
                    return (
                      <ChecklistItem

                        key={item.itemName}
                        indexOfItem={i}
                        checklistItem={item}
                        toggleCheck={this.check}
                        toggleCollapse={this.collapse}
                      />
                    );
                  })}
              </div>
)}
}

class ChecklistItem extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <li>{this.props.checklistItem.itemName}</li>
      <button onClick={() => this.props.toggleCheck(this.props.indexOfItem)}>Click me</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(<Checklists2/>, document.getElementById("root"));


<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: can you run it in some virtual hosts like **jsFiddle**? I need to run and test it @Louis

Comment: Do your items have ids? It's better to base actions (such as deletion) on ids than on indexes, especially when the list can be ordered like here.

Comment: @AmirmohammadMoradi https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/98382/ 

I created a fiddle,however the following NPM package is required: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/react-addons-update@15.6.2/index.min.js. When I add it to the fiddle, it doesn't work, but you should be able to run this locally pretty easily (I also simplified it a bit).

Thanks!